# The limit of integrals depending on a parameter

Tags: integration, limits

I have the following problem. The real function $f$ is defined for all $t\geq 1$ by

$$f(t)=\int\limits_1^t\frac{e^{x-t}}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx.$$

I want to show that $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}f(t)=0.$$

I should say that I am not sure that the above convergence holds, but I tried to compute the values of $f$ numerically, and they indeed seem to go to zero.

I have tried to formally exchange the limit and the integral, i.e. $$\lim_{t\to+\infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int\limits_1^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[1,t]}(x)\frac{e^{x-t}}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx =\int\limits_1^{\infty}\lim_{t\to+\infty}\left(\mathbb{1}_{[1,t]}(x)\frac{e^{x-t}}{\sqrt{x}}  \right)\, dx=\int\limits_1^{\infty}0\, dx=0,$$
where $\mathbb{1}_{[1,t]}$ is an indicator of interval $[1,t]$. The problem is that the monotone convergence theorem cannot be used (no monotonicity) and neither am I able to find an integrable majorant as I always run into $\int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx=+\infty.$

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use L'Hospital's Rule on $(\int_{1}^{t}x^{-1/2}e^x\,dx)/e^t$ and get the result immediately?

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using integration by parts :
$$ \int_1^t\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\left[\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\right]_1^t+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^t\frac{e^x}{x^{3/2}}dx $$
Thus
$$ f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-e^{1-t}+\frac{1}{2}\int_1^t\frac{e^{x-t}}{x^{3/2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^t\frac{e^{x-t}}{x^{3/2}}dx+o(1) $$
You can use the dominated convergence on
$$ g_t(x)=\frac{e^{x-t}}{x^{3/2}}1_{[1,t]}(x) $$
because $|g_t(x)|\leqslant\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\in L^{1}([1,+\infty[)$.